# Cron job stopped working after enabling ssl

Tags: php, ssl, cron, cpanel

I recently enabled SSL on my Prestashop site, but my 2 cronjobs stopped working with error:

```
Status: 301 Moved Permanently
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.25
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Cache-Control: no-cache
Location: https://www.xxxxxx.it
```

The cron command is: php /home/xxxxx/public_html/path/command.php
I cannot use wget or curl.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like your jobs are trying to trigger scripts via an HTTP request, but those now get redirected to HTTPS automatically. In that case, simple solution: Make them use the HTTPS URLs to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Check the cron logs at the path

/var/log/cron

and it will give you an idea of whats happening